# Как можно реализовать эффект внешнего свечения полосы?

Tags: css

Нужен эффект внешнего свечения полосы и чтобы сама полоска тоже была немного растушёвана.

```css
.home-logo { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px blue;
    border-radius: 50% ;
    height: 380px;
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
}

.home-logo .home-logo-bg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('/images/home-logo.png');
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
```

```html
                    <div class="home-logo">
                        <div class="home-logo-bg"></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может как-то так? Поработать со свойством `box-shadow`

```css
    .home-logo { 
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px blue;*/
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 144, 255, 0.15);
        border-radius: 50% ;
        height: 180px;
        width: 180px;
        margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="home-logo">
    <div class="home-logo-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Есть сайты генераторы, первый из [поиска](https://www.deposittemplates.com/box-shadow-generator/)